# show all breakpoints when debug a python code with pdb

Tags: python, debug, ipython

I am using pdb to debug a python code. I set the breakpoints in the pdb command line with b [linenumber]. Can I check all the linenumber of breakpoints? thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the `b` command with no arguments.

> Without argument, list all breaks, including for each breakpoint, the
>   number of times that breakpoint has been hit, the current ignore
>   count, and the associated condition if any.

from http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html